# Command line HDD to VHDX

Tags: windows, powershell, vhdx

Is it possible to create a Windows shadow volume copy of an HDD to a VHDX using powershell?

I got as far as simply creating an empty VHDX

```
$disk = New-VHD -Path "d:/test.vhdx" -Dynamic -SizeBytes 25GB
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [Disk2vhd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd) (a command line tool) but there are no native powershell command to do that.

> Usage: disk2vhd <[drive: [drive:]...]|[*]>